# I cloned a git repository. How do I pull from it into a working directory?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-clone

So I cloned an existing (and working) Git repository, for the purpose of experimenting with the clone (instead of pushing stuff into the live production repo).

[image]

It went without incident but now I would like to create a Working Directory to which I can pull from (and from which I can push to) the new "remote" repository I just created (cloned).

How do I do that?

I tried pulling to an empty directory with the help of `Git Extensions`, but all I get in the context menu are operations that do not seem like what I need:

[image]

Obviously, I am missing a key Git concept here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have selected the `--bare` option ("Public repository, no working dir"). This option does not create a working directory. Instead, choose the "Personal repository" option, which creates a working directory.

Comment: Thank you. All files are indeed in `D:\Repositories\LearningGit`. Does that mean that what I need to do now in order to have my working directory in `D:\working\LearningGit` is **clone from the clone**?

Comment: @datps: I updated my answer after I noticed that you had actually selected the `--bare` option. I think you don't want that option. You can create another clone from the clone you already cloned, if you want, but you can do it in one step instead of two.

Comment: Thanks again Greg. I think that you are gradually guiding me in this learning process, although I think that I did not explain my intent well enough. I *do* want to have **two** repositories, not one: The first mimicking our live "remote repository" (from/to which I can pull/push), the second serving as my 'working dir' (from which I can `add` & `commit`). Are you still suggesting that I should clone the first one as `Personal`?

Comment: @datps: Oh, ok in that case, you're on the right track. Create the first one with `--bare` so it doesn't have a working directory (like your server), and then create another new clone based on that new one, using the "Personal repository" option. The second clone will need to be in a different directory from the first one.

Comment: OK, this is clearer now. I just did as you suggested. It works but now I am surprised to see that the entire directory structure for the repository is different between the two: The `--barre` one has `hooks, info, objects, refs`. The 'Personal' one has `.git, Build, Installations, Scripts, Source`. Why is that? Where can I learn about the differences between a bare and personal clone?

Comment: @datps: Well, they're not completely different. Everything in the `--bare` one is also included in the `.git` directory of the full clone ("personal clone" in the terminology of your GUI). See [What is a bare git repository?](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: You are right! I should have compared the `--bare` one with the personal's `.git`. The .git subdirectory is identical except for having two extra items: `info/logs` subdirectory and and `index` file. Much clearer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While cloning, You should choose the 'personal repository' option of repository type to create the working directory.